# How can I copy something to the clipboard in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

How is it possible to copy something to the clipboard in c++?
I have searched for a solution but I can't find any examples.

Would be great if you have a code example aswell.
thank you

Comment: That's completely dependent on your OS and GUI framework, there's nothing supported by the c++ standard libraries to do so.

Comment: There are 3rd-party libraries for this, e.g. https://github.com/dacap/clip

Comment: I would like to have it for windows.

Comment: @Fisy then check the WinAPI documentation.

Comment: Documentation of clip-board API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard

Answer (score 0):

An example to copy a text into it.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* str = "Text copied to clipboard.";
    const size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;

    HGLOBAL hgl =  GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hgl), str, len);
    GlobalUnlock(hgl);

    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hgl);
    CloseClipboard();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can, but it is OS specified task.
Or just use QApplication::clipboard on Qt.